# Issues with Firestore Fucntions and PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a scheduled cloud function to Google Firebase, such as this

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

Anytime I deploy the schedule as "every 1 minutes" it gets deployed fine. However, if I try to do anything else, like "every 60 minutes", "every 8 hours", I get the following error.

I am not even getting information about the error so it is hard to debug.

```
exports.bookingReminder = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  let today = new Date()
  var dateArray = []
  let year = (today.getYear() - 100) + 2000
  dateArray.push(year.toString())
  var month = today.getMonth() + 1
  if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month.toString()
  }
  dateArray.push(month.toString())
  var day = today.getDate()
  if (day < 9) {
    day = "0" + day.toString()
  }
  dateArray.push(day.toString())
  let fullDate = dateArray.join("-")
  console.log(fullDate)
  const bookingsRef = admin.firestore().collection("bookings").where("date", "==", fullDate).get().then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      return null;
    }
    var emails = []
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log("yes found them on this date: " + fullDate)
      var booking = doc.data()
      var clients = booking.clients
      clients.forEach(client => {
        emails.push(client.email)
      })
      console.log(emails);
      const serviceRef = admin.firestore().collection("services").doc(booking.serviceId)
      let servie = {}
      const serviceSnap = serviceRef.get().then(doc2 => {
        service = doc2.data()
      }).then(() => {
        const msg = {
          //need client email
          to: emails, // Change to your recipient
          from: '', // Change to your verified sender
          //Booking Reminder
        };
        console.log("running email send")
        sgMail.send(msg);
      })
    })
    return emails;
  })
});
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "does not work"? How to you measure if it doesn't work? You can trigger the function manually from GCP console to see if it has any errors.

Comment: The function won't trigger immediately. Have you triggered it manually from the console or waited 8 hours to see if it triggers?

Comment: Hi guys, please see my edited question above. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Is it related to the Firebase pricing package I am signed up for?

Comment: @RemoBajwa please paste your whole code in text format in your question.